# Есть ли в JavaScript такие переменные?

Tags: javascript

Щас у меня такой код:

```
$("#1").click(function() {
    load(0);
    return false;
});
$("#2").click(function() {
    load(1);
    return false;
});
```

Мне нужно что-бы было что-то типа того:

```
$("#peremennaya").click(function() {
    peremennaya1 = peremennaya - 1;
    load(peremennaya1);
    return false;
});
$("#peremennaya").click(function() {
    peremennaya1 = peremennaya - 1;
    load(peremennaya1);
    return false;
});
```

То-есть вылавливать клики ссылок с айди #номер делать вычисление - 1, и загружать их, вызывая функцию load(вычесленный номер);

Если кто не понял, мне нужны переменные как тут:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9])$ index.php?mode=pages&id=$1
```

Comment: клики ловить вообще все, по всем элементам страницы, или есть какой-то класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная – `id` кликнутого элемента.

Надо ловить вообще все клики, смотреть, является ли `id` элемента, по которому кликнули, числом, и тогда выполнять ваши действия. Лучше как-то сузить ловлю кликов до элементов какого-то одного класса, или внутри одного родителя.

```
$(document.body).on('click', function(e) {
    var id = parseFloat(e.target.id);
    if( !( !isNaN(e.target.id) && (id | 0) === id)) return; // не число
    load( --id);
    return false;
});
```

Определение, является ли id числом, взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794066/556876).

---

Вообще, лучше бы вам **изменить разметку**. Дать всем кликабельным элементам общий класс, по которому их отличать, и в дата-атрибут записать значения для load:

```js
$('.load').on('click', function(){
  var n = $(this).data('n');
  load( n-1);
  return false;
});

var data = ['AAA','BBB','CCC'];
function load( m) {
  $('#out').text(data[m]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="load" href="#" data-n="1">A</a>
<a class="load" href="#" data-n="2">B</a>
<a class="load" href="#" data-n="3">C</a>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#2").click(function() {
    load(--this.id);
    return false;
});
```

проверяйте

Answer (score 0):

Если переменная содержит не только цифры но буквы например: id = "myId5";
То выручит конкатенация строки в аргументе при вызове jquery. Т.е:

```
 $("#myId5").click(function() {
//Берем id элемента и отделяем от него число, если числа двузначные то нужно либо сделать все числа двузначными или воспользоваться регулярными выражениями
   var a = ($(this).attr("id")).slice(0,-1);
// Преобразуем полученное число как нам нужно и вызываем необходимую функцию сложив строки в аргументе  
    a = parseInt(a) - 1;
    load("myId" + a);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: в примере: `attr("id")` -> `"2"`, и если ты возьмешь у этой строки `.slice(0,-1)` то в результате получишь пустую строку.

Comment: Совершенно верно, я написал это для случаев когда id содержит не только цифры(пример: id = "myId5"; ), но не изменил код. Спасибо.